# Mpdf use pdf template to create new pdf document

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

How to use "sample.pdf" as template to create new pdf document with Mpdf?

We have **one page** pdf template with large number of placeholders and we want to populate them.

We start learning with trying to generate copy of template without any data.

```
    $this->mpdf = new Mpdf(); 

    $this->mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $this->mpdf->SetCompression(false);
    $this->mpdf->SetSourceFile(APP . 'Template' . DS . 'Pdf' . DS . 'sample.pdf');
    $tpl = $this->mpdf->ImportPage(1); // *
    $this->mpdf->AddPage(); // *
    $this->mpdf->useTemplate($tpl); // *

    $this->mpdf->Output(TMP . 'test.pdf');
```

But "test.pdf" is blank.

**Update:**

Our sample.pdf has 911KB size, our test.pdf 1KB, but when comment lines // * our test.pdf have same size as sample.pdf but doc is blank / white page.

**UPDATE with working code** we have read other tuts.

```
    $this->mpdf->SetImportUse();
    $this->mpdf->SetDocTemplate(APP . 'Template' . DS . 'Pdf' . DS . 'sample.pdf', true);
    $this->mpdf->AddPage();

    $this->mpdf->Output(TMP . 'testpdf.pdf');
```

Comment: have you checked if `$tpl` has a value? could it be that the file is not being recognised due to the path?

Comment: @Oras yes, $tpl value is (int) 1

Comment: what happens if you move `$this->mpdf->AddPage();` below `use Template`?

Comment: @Oras, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

For creating document (PDF) with Templating PDF in **MPDF**

use `SetDocTemplate` Here is the  [official link](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setdoctemplate.html)

Below is one sample example code:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf( [ 
    'mode' => 'en-GB', 
    'format' => 'A4', 
    'default_font_size' => "", 
    'default_font' => "", 
    'margin_left' => $margin_left, 
    'margin_right' => $margin_right, 
    'margin_top' => $margin_top, 
    'margin_bottom' => $margin_bottom,
    'margin_footer' => $margin_footer, 
    'setAutoBottomMargin' => 'stretch',
    'setAutoTopMargin' => 'stretch', 'orientation'=>'P'
 ] );


$mpdf->SetDocTemplate('YOUR TEMPLATE PATH', true);  //HERE YOU CAN ATTACH THE PDF TEMPLATE HERE
  
$mpdf->WriteHTML('YOUR HTML CODE FOR PDF document');
$mpdf->Output('download.pdf', 'D'); // Download Created PDF
```